# adding/removing days from date code fix needed

Tags: java

I have this code here:

```
public static String AddRemoveDays(String date, int days) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat k = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date d = k.parse(date);
        d = new Date(d.getTime() + days*86400000);
        String time = k.format(d);

        return time;
    }
```

It take String formed "yyyyMMdd", and adds int days to it. It should work then the days is negative - then he would substract the days from the date. When it does it's math, it returns String formated "yyyyMMdd".

At least that is what it should do. It works for small numbers, but if I try to add (or remove), for example, a year (365 or -365), it returns wierd dates.

What's the problem?
Should I do it a completley another way?

Comment: What do you mean be "weird dates"? Note that adding 365 days is not necessarily the same as adding a year (see: step years).

Comment: Can you provide the problematic dates? What dates are you testing on? Not every year has 365 days, do not forget about leap years (which 2012 was).

Also, I would recommend using the `Calendar` class since `Date` is now deprecated in newer Java. A useful method is the `Calendar.getActualMaximum()` which will return the correct number of days in a year based on whether the current year is a leap year. Also, `Calendar` is much smarter with its internal math and will roll over various values as you increment the date.

Comment: I know it's not, it was just an example, that's why I'm calculating with miliseconds.
Try arguments ("20120605", 365), or ("20120605", 45).
How could I do it with the calendar?

Comment: @gnomed: Where have you seen that Date was deprecated? It's not. And there is no SimpleCalendarFormat anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet True, the entire class is not deprecated, but pretty much every method inside it is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

It is intended solely as a lightweight wrapper for a millisecond timestamp and primarily for SQL (JDBC) compatibility purposes. It is also acceptable to use as a transitional structure between `SimpleDateFormat` (or any other dateformat) and `Calendar`. While `Date` can represent a time alright, `Calendar` is easily more ideal for manipulating date/times.

Comment: Although I think Date *should* be deprecated and replaced by something like joda-time, a Date and a Calendar are actually very different, and both have their usage. A Date is a universal instant in time. A Calendar is this instant in time for a specific time zone, locale, and calendaring system (gregorian, etc.). When you need a universal instant in time (which is very often the case), Date is the right class to use, and is also more lightweight.

Comment: @JBNizet Date is the right class to use until you have to start adding days, or hours or years to the date in memory. Rather than doing the calculations in milliseconds (which you are bound to screw up with all the DST transitions and leap years and other time adjustments), the Calendar class is significantly safer and accomodates a larger range of dates (you dont have to remember when leap years started being observed, or which countries or states have strange DST rules, it all just works, try doing that with millisecond calculations)

Comment: I agree with that. I'm just saying that using Calendar as a systematic replacement for Date is not wise.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed, a systematic replacement would be bad. I concede that Calendar is significantly more heavyweight. But for datetime modifications, I love it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    d = new Date(d.getTime() + days*86400000);
```

If you multiply 86400000 by 365 integer cant hold it. Change 86400000 to Long

```
    d = new Date(d.getTime() + days*86400000L);
```

and it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I can add/remove thousands of years now! =)

Comment: Although the OP should probably use something more accurate (like Joda Time or Calendar), this answer does exactly what he asked for. +1

Comment: @Karlovsky120 -- 86400000 * 1000 != 1000 years.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell what do you mean? 86400000 * 1000 != 1000 years ago because method is adding 1000 days not years.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for pointing that out... what I meant was `86400000 * 1000 != 1000 days`.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say what's going on without specific dates.

If you're committed to doing this with the raw Java classes, you might want to look at using `Calendar` -e.g.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(d);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, days); // this supports negative values for days;
d = calendar.getTime();
```

That said, I would recommend steering clear of the java `Date` classes, and look to use [jodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or [jsr310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen) instead.

e.g. in jsr310, you could use a `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate`:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatters.pattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate orig = format.parse(dateString, LocalDate.rule());
LocalDate inc = orig.plusDays(days); // again, days can be negative;
return format.print(inc);
```